# How to repeat query for each record in another table? SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I have a `.txt` file which contains data that has to be stored in a table and I have written a query for that.

The problem is that there are many `.txt` files and more can be added, I think a table with the `.txt` files names could be made. I need to run the query for each file, using those names as a variable.

This is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE #textfile (line varchar(8000)) 

BULK INSERT #textfile 
FROM 'c:\MXAPT1_SNDA01_1_SSD.TXT' 
GO 

-- Now read it and insert 
INSERT INTO san3parvols(disco, tipo, fecha, totcap, alloc, disp)
    (SELECT 
         disco, tipo, fecha, 
         SUM(totcap) AS totcap, SUM(alloc) AS alloc,
         SUM(totcap) - SUM(alloc) AS disp  
     FROM
        (SELECT 
             'MXAPT1_SNDA01_TRIARA_1' as disco, 'SSD' AS tipo, 
             CASE 
                WHEN substring(line,3,4) = 'tal' 
                   THEN 'Total Capacity' 
                   EKSE 'Allocated' 
             END AS valor, 
             CAST(substring(line, PatIndex('%[0-9]%', line), LEN(line)) AS numeric(18,2)) AS cap,
             CONVERT(DATE, getdate()) AS fecha,
             CAST(CASE 
                     WHEN substring(line, 3, 4) = 'tal'
                        THEN substring(line, PatIndex('%[0-9]%', line), LEN(line)) 
                        ELSE 0 
                  END AS numeric(18,2)) AS totcap,
             CAST(CASE 
                     WHEN substring(line, 3, 4) = 'Allo'
                        THEN substring(line, PatIndex('%[0-9]%', line), len(line)) 
                        ELSE 0 
                  END AS numeric(18,2)) AS alloc
         FROM 
             #textfile  
         WHERE
             substring(line, 3, 4) IN ('tal', 'Allo')) AS txt1
GROUP BY
    disco, tipo, fecha)

-- And then clean up 
DROP TABLE #textfile 
GO
```

I know you can help and I give you thanks in advance.

EDIT

Just in case someone needs  the answer to my last question to M.Ali i share the code about how to add multiple variables.

```
Declare @File Nvarchar(max), @sql Nvarchar(max), @name Nvarchar(max), @tipo Nvarchar(max);

Declare Cur CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR 
SELECT trespar, name, tipo
FROM sanparlist 

OPEN Cur 

  FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @File, @name, @tipo  

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN

   TRUNCATE TABLE Textfile_Stagging_table

   SET @Sql = N' BULK INSERT Textfile_Stagging_table 
                 FROM ''' + @File + ''''

   Execute sp_executesql @Sql

   INSERT INTO san3parvols(disco, tipo, fecha,totcap, alloc, disp)
(SELECT disco, tipo, fecha, sum(totcap) AS totcap, sum(alloc) AS alloc,sum(totcap)-sum(alloc) AS disp  FROM 
(SELECT @name AS disco, @tipo AS tipo, 
        CASE WHEN substring(line,3,4) = 'tal'THEN 'Total Capacity' ELSE 'Allocated' END AS valor, 
        cast(substring(line, PatIndex('%[0-9]%', line), len(line)) AS numeric(18,2) )AS cap,
        convert(DATE,getdate()) AS fecha,
        cast(CASE WHEN substring(line,3,4) = 'tal'THEN substring(line, PatIndex('%[0-9]%', line), len(line)) ELSE 0 END AS numeric(18,2)) AS totcap,
        cast(CASE WHEN substring(line,3,4) = 'Allo'THEN substring(line, PatIndex('%[0-9]%', line), len(line)) ELSE 0 END AS numeric(18,2)) AS alloc
FROM Textfile_Stagging_table  
WHERE substring(line,3,4) in('tal','Allo')) AS txt1
GROUP BY disco, tipo, fecha)

     FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @File, @name, @tipo  
END

CLOSE Cur 
DEALLOCATE Cur;
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but I am not quite sure what your question is. Are you wanting to import data from a variable collection of text files into a table in your database?

Comment: Yes exactly  and i can do it succesfully if i repeat the code for each .txt file. The  challenge is  how to  run the query as many times as  .txt files names  i have stored in certain table.. like a loop.. Thank very much for answering. please let me know if got any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to have file names in a table and to write a query to get the Text file name from the table and insert them into your database.

---

```
-- Create a Table in SQL Server 

CREATE TABLE Textfile_Stagging_table (line varchar(8000)) 
GO
```

1. Create Cursor to loop through the table containing txt file details.
2. Say your table is called "TxtFile" and has a column FileName containing Full path with the text file name to be imported.

---

```
Declare @File Nvarchar(max), @sql Nvarchar(max);

Declare Cur CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR 
SELECT [FileName]
FROM TxtFiles 

OPEN Cur 

  FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @File  

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN

   TRUNCATE TABLE Textfile_Stagging_table

   SET @Sql = N' BULK INSERT Textfile_Stagging_table 
                 FROM ''' + @File + ''''

   Execute sp_executesql @Sql

   -- Your original query to get data into final destination table
   -- from the Stagging table can go here 

   -- insert into san3parvols(disco, tipo, fecha,totcap, alloc, disp)
   -- Select bla bla bla 
   -- FROM Textfile_Stagging_table

     FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @File  
END

CLOSE Cur 
DEALLOCATE Cur;
```

Comment: Thank  you M.Ali. i´ll try it right away and i will let you know how it went.. Thank you again

Comment: IT worked like a charm and this is perfect.. i have a bounch  .txt files to process in  diferente queries.. thank you Sr.  No just one las question.. How can i  add more variables to fill  the name and type in my query?